# Override mp3 from framework iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, frameworks

Does anyone know how to override framework resources (mp3 in my case) in an app using said framework? On android its just a case of creating a resource with the same name and file path in the app directory. Haven't been able to find any such way on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

use `bundleWithIdentifier` to get the frameworks's bundle , then access it like this

```
 let path = frameworkBundle.path(forResource: "Test", ofType: "mp3")
```